# Enhanced playback with Spotify API

Tags: audio, spotify, playback, transcription

Is there anyway I can get better playback controls?  For example I'd like to be able to carefully scrub through playback, like if I were learning a guitar solo or something.  I might like to slow down, frequency morph, etc.  Is the audio playback locked down pretty tight or can I control how the audio hits my sound card?

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this without a lot of unofficial hacking. Try http://www.soundslice.com/, it is designed for that, and is backed mostly by youtube videos afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the API Terms of Service prevent you from doing this sort of audio manipulation to Spotify's audio.